# Understanding Apollo client caching and optimistic UI in AWS AppSync JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I am trying to implement caching in Apollo client with the AWS AppSync JavaScript SDK but I am struggling to understand first the best way to use the cache and second what if any changes I need to make to adapt the Apollo V2 tutorials to work with the AppSync SDK.

With regards to using the cache, I have a list of objects that I get, I then want to view and modify a single object from this list. There are lots of tutorials on how to update something in a list, but I would rather run a second query that gets a single object by its ID so that the page will always work without having to go through the list first.

Is the cache smart enough to know that object X got through queries Y and Z is the same object and will be updated at the same time? If not, is there any documentation on how to write an update that will update the object in the list and by itself at the same time?

If no documentation exists then I will try and work it out on my own and post the code (because it will most likely not work).

With regards to the second question I have got the application working and querying the API using Amplify for authentication but I am unsure as to how to correctly implement the cache. Do I need to specify the cache when creating the client or does the SDK have a built-in cache? How do I access the cache? Is it just by querying the client as in these tutorials? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to answer your second question first:

> With regards to the second question I have got the application working and querying the API using Amplify for authentication but I am unsure as to how to correctly implement the cache. Do I need to specify the cache when creating the client or does the SDK have a built-in cache? How do I access the cache? Is it just by querying the client as in these tutorials?

Ok. So here is where is gets a little hairy -- it looks like AppSync was deployed at a time when the major client libraries for GraphQL (Apollo, Relay, etc.) were getting an overhaul, so AWS actually created a wrapper around the Apollo Client (probably for stable API purposes) and then exposed their own way of doing things. Just a quick rundown through the code looks like they have their own proprietary and undocumented way of doing things [that involves websockets, their authentication protocols, a redux store, offline functionality, ssr, etc](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/blob/master/packages/aws-appsync/src/client.ts)). Thus, if it is not explicitly explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/system-overview-and-architecture.html) or [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js), you're in uncharted territory.

Fortunately, all of the stuff that they provided (and much, much more) has *now* been implemented in the underlying Apollo Client in a **documented** way. Even more fortunately, it looks like the AppSync client forwards most of the actual GraphQL related stuff directly to the internal Apollo Cache and allows you to pass in config options under `cacheOptions`, so most of the configuration you can do with the Apollo Client you can do with the AppSync Client (more below).

Unfortunately, you cannot access the cache directly with the AppSync client (they've hidden it to make sure their public API remains stable in the fluctuating ecosystem). However, if you really need more control, most of the stuff they have implemented in the AppSync client could easily be replicated in your own instantiation of an Apollo Client wherein you'd unlock full control (you can use the [open-source AppSync code](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/tree/master/packages/aws-appsync) as a foundation). Since GraphQL frontends and backends are decoupled, there is no reason why you couldn't use your own Apollo Client to connect with the AppSync server (for a large, serious project, this is what I would do as the Apollo Client is much better documented and under active development).

> Is the cache smart enough to know that object X got through queries Y and Z is the same object and will be updated at the same time? If not, is there any documentation on how to write an update that will update the object in the list and by itself at the same time?

*This first part pertains to both the Apollo Client and the AppSync client.*

Yes! That's one of the great things about Apollo client - every time you make a query it tries to update the cache. The cache is a normalized key-value store where all of the objects are stored at the top level which the key being a combination of the `__typename` and `id` properties of the object. The Apollo client will automatically add `__typename` to all of your queries (though you will have to add `id` to your queries manually - otherwise it falls back to just the query path itself as the key [which is not very robust]).

The [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#configuration) provide a very good overview of the mechanism.

Now, you may need to do some more advanced stuff. For example, if your GraphQL schema uses some unique object identifier other than `id`, you'll have to provide some function to the `dataIdFromObject` that maps to it.

Additionally, sometimes when making queries, it is difficult for the cache to know exactly what you are asking for to check the cache before making a network request. To alleviate this problem, they provide the [cache redirect](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#cacheRedirect) mechanism.

Finally, and perhaps most complicated, is how to work with updating the order of stuff in paginated queries (e.g., anything that is in an ordered list). To do this, you'll have to use the [@connection](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#connection-directive) directive. Since this is based on the [relay connection spec](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm), I'd recommend giving that a skim.

Bonus: To see the cache in action, I'd recommend the [Apollo client dev tools](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-devtools). It's a little buggy, but it will at least give you some insight into what it actually happening to the cache locally -- this will not work if using AppSync.

---

So besides the above information which is all about setting up and configuring the cache, you can also control the data and access to the cache during the runtime of your app (if using Apollo Client directly and not the AppSyncClient).

The [Direct Cache Access docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#direct) specify the available methods. However, since most of the updates happen automatically just based on the queries you make, you shouldn't have to use these often. However, one use for them is for complicated UI updates. For example, if you make a mutation that deletes an item from a list, instead of requerying for the entire list (which *would* update the cache, though at the expense of more network data, parsing, and normalization) you could defined a custom cache update using `readQuery`/`writeQuery` and the `update` mutation option. This also plays nicely with [optimisticResponse](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/optimistic-ui.html) which you should use if you're looking for optimistic UI.

Additionally, you can choose whether you want to use or bypass the cache (or some more advanced strategy) using one of the [fetchPolicy or errorPolicy options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.query).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much that is an incredible answer! I had been thinking that moving to the plain Apollo client was a good idea for a while now and this just confirms it.